# How to tell Typescript interpreter that variable will be a specific type in the runtime

Tags: typescript

I have a method that accepts argument of either `string` or `MyEnum` type and has a return type of only `MyEnum`. Also, there is a check - if a given argument is of `MyEnum` type, it will be returned immediately, otherwise additional logic is applied.

But when I want to do that I get this error:

> Type 'string | MyEnum' is not assignable to type 'MyEnum'.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'MyEnum'.

My code:

```
export enum MyEnum {
    Value1 = 1,
    Other = 10
}

export function TextToEnum(text: string | MyEnum): MyEnum {
    if (typeof text === typeof MyEnum)
        return text;

    switch (text) {
      case "val1":
        return MyEnum.Value1;
      default:
        return MyEnum.Other;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `typeof` check to use `"number"` instead of `typeof MyEnum`:

```
export function TextToEnum(text: string | MyEnum): MyEnum {
    if (typeof text === "number")
        return text;

    switch (text) {
      case "val1":
        return MyEnum.Value1;
      default:
        return MyEnum.Other;
    }
}
```

The reason why `typeof MyEnum` doesn't work is because `typeof` always has the same string union type:

```
"string" | "number" | "bigint" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" | "function"
```

and therefore conveys no type information.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwLIE8CiL0DeAsAFBzlwBqAhgDbLACMcAvHIwDSkVwDyMAC2BRW7AAykAvqVKhIsOADNkiAMYwAlhERwAKqBi6IeNAAoYBgFxwAzjCgbEAczgAfTLnwBKa9hOFuCg1FOHMsMGAIEIsQeBZ4uAAifAAjYUSvQJ5yKGAYZCgdGJgAbhkyChsAdw0YVQFQ4q84YgqeVWobYCSANzpGRMss7Nz8wo9-ADoaeiYytooAE2BFamRaGCGFnlGCnT98Sf4hKHmeaRJJIA)

---

Alternatively, you can check if it isn't a string:

```
export function TextToEnum(text: string | MyEnum): MyEnum {
    if (typeof text !== "string")
        return text;

    // ...
}
```

and it'll also work.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwLIE8CiL0DeAsAFBzlwBqAhgDbLACMcAvHIwDSkVwDyMAC2BRW7AAykAvqVKhIsOADNkiAMYwAlhERwAKqBi6IeNAAoYBgFxwAzjCgbEAczgAfTLnwBKa9hOFuCg1FOHMsMGAIEIsQeABCFjYAIjsHZySvQJ5yKGAYZCgdGJgAbhkyChsAdw0YVQFQ4q84YgqeVWobYDgkgDc6RiTLLOzc-MKPfwA6GnomMraKABNgRWpkWhhhxZ4xgp0-fCn+ISgFnmkSSSA)

Answer (score 0):

The `typeof` operator can feel a bit confusing sometimes in TypeScript, since TypeScript has its own version of it that can be used when defining types. But when it's used with values, like in your example, it is a built-in JavaScript operator.

To do this sort of type narrowing safely, you need to use a custom typeguard function, which allows you to tell TypeScript how to do type narrowing for a custom type. You can create these functions using TypeScript's `is` keyword in the return type annotation. See [Using type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)

Here's an example of a function that can create a custom typeguard for an enum:

```js
export function isEnum<E>(
    enumToCheck: Record<string, E>
): (value: unknown) => value is E {
    const values = Object.values(enumToCheck);

    return function isEnumToCheck(value: unknown): value is E {
        return (values as Array<unknown>).includes(value);
    };
}
```

So you could use that to create a custom typeguard for your enum like this:

```js
const isMyEnum = isEnum(MyEnum);
```

And then use it like this:

```js
if (isMyEnum(text)) { return text; }
```

Of course, if you only need the one specific typeguard you won't need to use a factory function, and you could use the same approach to make yourself an `isMyEnum` typeguard function directly.